# Coworker sneezes then says "Gesundheit" herself. Is this wrong sneezing etiquette?

Tags: professionalism

One side is: "Just say 'Excuse me.' Let others say 'Bless you!' or 'Gesundheit!'"

The other side says, "What if no one is around?" [answer: no one will care] or "Why can't I?"

I think the whole point of the exercise -- superstition aside -- is a tiny social transaction that requires others. I don't think it is a hard wrong to bless yourself, but in my experience it is generally done as joke after a loud sneeze or a series of sneezes.

If she likes doing it, that's fine, too. It's probably common for some to do this but they're people I haven't met, save one misguided soul.

Anyway... Dukes Up!

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: Is it wrong to bless yourself or say Gesundheit after you yourself sneeze?

Comment: Only if it's wrong for me to clap the bottom of my shoes after sneezing, maybe with an occasional peppy jump to go with it.

Comment: If she's not a German speaker, she might even think Gesundheit means 'excuse me' and is what you're supposed to say after sneezing.  Why does it matter?

Comment: Does your company have specific policies about "sneezing etiquette" while on premises?

Comment: Probably the most amusing downvoted question on this site.

Answer (score 11):

> Is this wrong sneezing etiquette?

No. As per the Sneezing Etiquette Handbook, 2019 Edition, it is okay to bless oneself by saying 'Gesundheit!' after a sneeze.

Comment: Point of correction: "Gesundheit" means "be healthy" and is a secular term that precludes any blessing.

Comment: A point of clarification: this was codified in 2018 but wasn't officially enacted until the Sneezing Etiquette Handbook of 2019. Anyone who is wondering how to deal with this for sneezes occurring prior to it's official enactment is free to follow the previously issued guidelines. ;)

Comment: This issue is not as clear-cut as you're making it out to be. IANAL, but the Sneezing Etiquette Handbook - while an excellent guide to the uninitiated - really doesn't do the complexity of the issue justice. I suggest that the OP seek legal advice before reaching any final conclusions.

Comment: Maybe the company policy does not adhere to the 2019 international sneezing standards.  OP should definitely ask their department's Sneeze Manager, or consult a lawyer who has studied sneeze law.

Comment: I would take this up with Human Sneezesources.